# Iterate through a text file line by line c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-runtime, storage

Basically this is the code I currently have;

```
public async void readTextFile()
{      
    try {
        StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.VideosLibrary;
        StorageFile storageFile = await folder.GetFileAsync("students.txt");

        string text = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            the_name.Text = "{0} Exception caught." + e;
        }
    }
}
```

The text file has a list of students that is laid out like this

Student Name|false

Student Second|false

With the names of 10 students and the word false to specify whether they've taken the test in the app, if they have taken it false reverts to true.

What my question is. How can I iterate through every line in that text file and store the one that has been typed in the textbox in a variable?

Just to note: I'm creating a windows desktop store application

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the ReadTextAsync method, you can use the ReadLinesAsync method and then loop through the results and split on the pipe character to find what you are looking for.

Comment: so create a string due to not being able to implicitly convert that specific type to a string then use a while loop to loop through every line put the line in a variable and use string.split at the pipe and check if the text to the left of the pipe is the same as the text inputted?